# Can you extend 2 things in an activity on android studio? Using getreadabledatabase outside SQLiteopenhelper

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Hey guys so i want to use getReadableDatabase() in my main activity but the problem is that it is already extending appCompatActivity() and i need it to do that for my code. But now since i cant extend 2 things at a time ,i cant extend SQLiteOpenHelper and that leads to not being able to use getreadable. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Create two classes.

Comment: 2 identical classes? isnt that a bad thing

Comment: Two *different* classes: [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: makes sense thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define create a second class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper and define methods within there that use getReadableDatabase(). You can set up SQLiteOpenHelper as a singleton so that you can access a single instance of the class from anywhere.

See http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2018/01/refactoring-sqliteopenhelper-so-it-isnt-a-mile-long/ for how you can structure your SQLiteOpenHelper class.